# Cannot select table with JSON data type

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to try JSON data type in MySQL. I am getting this warning:

[image]

I already updated MySQL version of the server to 5.7.13
and I also updated Adminer to version 4.2.5

[image]

I did the same thing in my localhost, and I get no warnings.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance. PS. this is my first question in SO :)

Comment: Same thing happening here. The [mysqlnd](http://docs.php.net/mysqlnd) implementation of your php version doesn't know that field type yet, though [there is code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.0/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c#L1656) for the json type in mysqlnd. Have you tried he latest and greatest php version (7.0.7 atm)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

JSON data type was added in [Adminer 4.3.0 (released 2017-03-15)](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/master/changes.txt).

#### [Adminer Bootstrap-Like Design](https://github.com/natanfelles/adminer-bootstrap-like)

[image]

Comment: you should try migrating to the latest version of PHP which is 7.

although I wasnt able to try that, I end up just using the string data type instead of JSON, and also I've already designated to another project.

Comment: Yes. It happened in PHP 7.0.18 with Adminer 4.2.5. When I updated the Adminer to version 4.3.1 the JSON data type appeared in the select field.

Comment: Great! :) enjoy the functions of that JSON data type. happy coding... as for me I shifted to Swift programming.